# Can't I use hg update offline?

Tags: mercurial, offline, tortoisehg

When I use Mercurial and try to do a

```
hg update --repository C:\Projekt\Learnify\Systems\myapp -rev 271 --check
```

without network connection I get

```
"URLError getaddrinfo failed".
```

Shouldn't I be able to to this since the actual repository is on my computer?

Comment: It should be either `--rev 271 or -r 271`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

another guess is that you have a subrepository reference in your repository that has an absolute path to a remote location and you are updating to a changeset in your parent repository that references a changeset in the subrepository that you don't have locally, so it is trying to do a pull on that remote repository that is referenced as a subrepository.  so what is preventing your update is not a need to connect to a remote repository for your repository itself, but for the subrepository that is referenced absolutely.

Comment: BINGO!, I was sure that I had properly set it up but when checking the .hgsub it pointed to a remote server. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

try

```
hg update --repository file://C:\Projekt\Learnify\Systems\myapp -rev 271 --check
```

to tell Hg it is not a network protocol URI

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you are using a shared repository (one that cloned with 'hg share' instead of 'hg clone' command). That means the history had been never cloned. You can check for a file '.hg/sharedpath'. If this file exists then actual repo is located elsewhere.

I'd suggest when you'll back online, make another clone of your repository.